# Ref from class to functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I use `ref` from parent class to access child class.

However in this case I want to access from parent class to child functional component.

in parent class.

```
class Waveform extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.track_0Ref = React.createRef();
  }
  handlePlay = () => {
    console.log("play button click");
    var node = this.track_0Ref.current
    console.log(node); //  show null......
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AudioTrack trackNum="0" ref={this.track_0Ref}/>
    )
  }
}
```

in child functional component.

```
const AudioTrack = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {});
  return(  
    <GridContainer>
    <PlayButton onClick={this.handlePlay} />
    <div id=track0 ></div>
    </GridContainer>
  );
}
```

It seems there is no object `this.track_0Ref.current` in parent class...

Where should I wrong??

Comment: Which object exactly do you expect in the ref? What would you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AudioTrack` needs to forward the `ref` it was provided via `props.ref` to an actual DOM element.

e.g.

```
<div id="track0" ref={props.ref}/>
```

Comment: I see maybe I thought wrong. ref is for the dom object not component itself. thank you very much